# Multiple Site Manager Can't Add Site EE 1.6.8

Tags: multiple-sites

I need to add two sites to my Multiple Site Manager in Expression Engine 1.6.8.  There are 24 microsites already.  The first I added, and it looks ok, but I do not get the "Create a New Site" link when I go to "Edit Sites".  I'm worried that the database has too many columns or something like that.   Any suggestions?

Comment: 6 year old EE? It'll only get worse if you don't work on an upgrade path. And with new versions of PHP coming out, you're continuing to fall behind. Not trying to be a jerk, but I would highly suggest you push your employer to upgrade. It's only going to get harder, and when something really breaks, upgrading and fixing it gets exponentially harder as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you run out of number of available sites for your MSM license. Check that in your purchases section on EllisLab's site.

Not sure though you'll be able to purchase more, as EE1 is not supported officially anymore.

Comment: You can still buy additional sites for MSM/EE 1, yes. That said, upgrading to EE2 should really become a priority.